# Why is the index value changing?

Tags: python, arrays, loops

Here is my code.

```py
import numpy as np

m = 2
n = 2

arr = [[0]*m]*n

for i in np.arange(n):
    for j in np.arange(m):
        print(i)
        arr[i][j] = i

print(arr)
```

the output is:

```
0
0
1
1
[[1,1],[1,1]]
```

I do not understand why the output array is not [[0,0],[1,1]].
Please I am losing my mind.

Comment: Have a look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `[0]*m` object is being repeated `n` times. Whatever your `i` you're changing the same object, so you see only the last change printed.

`arr = [[0]*m for _ in range(n)]` solves the problem

Comment: I see so both inner arrays are views of the same array. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You're welcome.